# Summable Sequences

Tags: real-analysis

By using,"Let {$a_n$} be a sequence of real numbers and let $\alpha_n=\frac{a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n}{n}$, for all n $\in$ N. Then we say that {$a_n$} is (C,1) summable or Cesaro convergent to A iff {$\alpha_n$} converges to A." to show that the sequence {$a_n$}, where 
$a_n=
\begin{cases}
\frac{n+1}{2}, & \text{if $n$ is odd} \\ 
\frac{-n}{2}, & \text{if n is even}
\end{cases}$,
is not (C,1) summable.

Comment: what is $a_n$ when $n$ is even?

Comment: {$a_n$} when $n$ is even should be $\frac{-n}{2}$. Sorry still getting the hang of this format

Answer (score 1):

If $n$ is even, say $n = 2k$, then there will be $k$ pairs, whose difference is $\frac{1}{2}$. Thus $\alpha_{2k} = \frac{1}{4}$

If $n$ is odd, say $n = 2k+1$, there will be $k$ pairs, whose difference is $\frac{1}{2}$ plus one term $a_{2k+1}$ left. Thus $\alpha_{2k+1} = \frac{k/2+k+1}{2k+1} \to \frac{3}{4}$

$2$ different sub-sequences converge to $2$ different limits, so...